# Convert flags enum to binary string representation

Tags: c#, string, enums, byte

Take this enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Colors
{
  NONE = 0,
  RED = 1,
  BLUE = 2,
  YELLOW = 4,
  BLACK = 8,
  WHITE = 16
}
```

I want to save a selection of those colors as a human readable string that represents a byte. For example,

```
Colors choice = Colors.RED | Colors.WHITE
```

should come out as

```
"00010001"
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `string result = Convert.ToString((int) choice, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make the representation step by step:

1. We want integer, not `enum`: `(int) choice`
2. Be in binary format `Convert.ToString((int) choice, 2)`
3. Finally, we want *at least* `8` digits; so we have to pad by `'0'` if necessary: `.PadLeft(8, '0')`

Combining all together:

```
 string result = Convert.ToString((int) choice, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Comment: Adding a link to the used [Convert.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_) overload and also the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) article about radix/ base